# Network Flow : True or False

Tags: algorithm, network-flow

```
In a directed graph with at most one edge between each pair of vertices, if we
replace each directed edge by an undirected edge, the maximum flow 
value remains unchanged.
```

Why is it false?

Why and how will flow change?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to prgramming

Comment: It is related to programming.

Comment: @JayPatel: There's nothing in the question about programming at the moment. If this is about programming, can you update the question to explain how? Otherwise the question might be more appropriate on either the [computer science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/) or [mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/) sites, rather than here.

Comment: @JayPatel: The purpose of a homework question like this is to get you to try out several examples, to see if you can find one that works.  In this case, not much experimenting is required to find an example that works, and if you simply repeat the question here without trying anything, you won't learn anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the edge could be the wrong way around. There are more interesting cases, but consider this trivial one:

```
S <- T
```

The flow is zero regardless of the capacity of the edge. If you make it undirected, the flow will be whatever the capacity of the edge is.